# How to globally configure ASP.NET Core 6+ API routes to be formatted as kebab-case when generated from controller names?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project. Some of the endpoints are related to controllers whose names consist of multiple words and thus are in PascalCase format as per the convention in .NET. Suppose I have a `PackageGroupsController`. I'd like its route to be `/package-groups` instead of the default `/PackageGroups` and I don't want to specify a hardcoded route for each controller. How can I achieve that using a global configuration or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AddControllers` allows you to customize conventions used, you can try using those with [`RouteTokenTransformerConvention`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.routetokentransformerconvention?view=aspnetcore-7.0). Something like:

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers(opts => 
    opts.Conventions.Add(new RouteTokenTransformerConvention(new ToKebabParameterTransformer())));

public class ToKebabParameterTransformer : IOutboundParameterTransformer
{
    public string TransformOutbound(object? value) => value != null 
        ? Regex.Replace(value.ToString(), "([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1-$2").ToLower() // to kebab 
        : null; 
}
```

Comment: thanks but this turns `PascalCase` into `pasca-ase`

Comment: @Geekmard works completely fine for me - [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3jGF.png) (I have tested it before posting the answer). Can you provide a [mre] for not working version? Also you can always change actual code for `TransformOutbound` to match your case/need, the main point of answer is to show how and where you can try to extend the pipeline.

Comment: Sorry, there was a problem with my browser printing "$1-$2" due to an extension's misbehavior. This works fine.